# Ensure download was completed

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I am using a `for` loop in which **Webclient** class `Downloadstring()` method is used to load a external url .
The Url has been provided by SMS service provider in which Mobile number and the message to be transmitted is added.
But message is not being submitted to SMS gateway for all mobile numbers specified in `phNos[]` array ie downloading Url is skipped for some numbers . This occurs mostly for mobile numbers at end of array.
How can I ensure that program waits until url is  loaded for particular number and then the program progresses forward.

```
WebClient cli = new WebClient();
for (i=0;i<phNos.Length;i++)
{
    string url = @"http://example.com?DestNo=" + phNos[i] + "&msg=" + message; 
    cli.DownloadString(url);  
}
```

Alternately I have also used  `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` but the problem persist.

```
  for (i=0;i<phNos.Length;i++)
    {
        string url = @"http://example.com?DestNo=" + phNos[i] + "&msg=" + message; 
        Uri targetUri = new Uri(url);
        HttpWebRequest hwb = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);

        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = hwb1.GetResponse();
        int status = (int)response.StatusCode;

        if (status == 200)
        {

            Response.Write("Successfully transmitted" + status);
        }
    }
```

Is there any other alternative method to ensure message is submitted 100 %.

Comment: As you're using the synchronous call, that really *will* already be waiting. (It would be simpler to use a `foreach` loop, by the way.) I suggest you look at what's happening in Wireshark - I suspect the problem isn't where you think it is.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you can ensure when program reaches next instruction after for loop.

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan Yes program executes code after for loop execution is completed.

Comment: Have you tried checking the response from the service to see if there is an error returned or something?

Comment: @Karl-Johan Sjögren Yes , I am checking against status code 200 , and I get it for all numbers . Please wait , I will post the edited code

Comment: Well 200 can be sent by the server anyway and then the text might be something like "ERROR", so your request might be fine but the result on the server (ie. sending the sms) might have failed for some reason. Try checking the actual response content.

Comment: @ Karl-Johan Sjögren . Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. DownloadString is blocking and if an error occurs it should raise an exception. How does the SMS gateway respond to your request? You should have a look at their documentation, because probably you can write a function that tests whether everything worked fine or not.

```
const int MAX_RETRY = 10;
WebClient cli= new WebClient();

for(i=0;i<phNos.Length;i++)
{
    url = @"http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd?DestNo=" + phNos[i] + "&msg=" + message;

    int cntRetry = 0;

    while (!TestResult(cli.DownloadString(url)) && cntRetry < MAX_RETRY)
        ++cntRetry;
}
```

The problem could be that you are submitting too many requests to the gateway in a very short time. You could try to put some **Thread.Sleep(1000)** calls somewhere and see if things get any better.

```
WebClient cli= new WebClient();
for(i=0;i<phNos.Length;i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    url = @"http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd?DestNo=" + phNos[i] + "&msg=" + message; 
    cli.DownloadString(url);  
}
```

You could also combine the two above examples, using maybe lower values for **MAX_RETRY** and **Thread.Sleep**.

```
const int MAX_RETRY = 5;
WebClient cli= new WebClient();

for(i=0;i<phNos.Length;i++)
{
    url = @"http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd?DestNo=" + phNos[i] + "&msg=" + message;

    int cntRetry = 0;

    while (!TestResult(cli.DownloadString(url)) && cntRetry < MAX_RETRY) {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        ++cntRetry;
    }
}
```

Comment: While your program sleeps is not really making a request; it is waiting before two requests, in order to give the SMS server enough time to *recover*. SMS gateways have a capacity, a maximum number of SMSs per second that you can send; the capacity also depends on the kind of contract that you have with the service, and is likely to be higher for customers who pay more. Have a look at the site of the SMS gateway: you should find detailed information including how to place requests, including timing constraints, and how to interpret the server response.

Comment: When I said *before* two requests, I should have said *in between* two requests.

Answer (score 1):

I would instantiate a webclient for every call and dispose it after downloadstring is called, like so

```
foreach(var phone in phNos)
{
  using(WebClient cli= new WebClient())
  {
     url = String.Format(@"http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd?DestNo={0}&msg={1}", phone, message); 
     string result = cli.DownloadString(url); 
     // check if result has somekind of errorreport maybe? 
     Trace.WriteLine(result);  // optionally write it to a trace file
  }
}
```

Getting it disposed explicitely might help in also closing underlying networkconnections more quickly because I suspect the sheer number of connections are causing the issue. Throttling might also be an option (send less calls to the gateway per minute)

If this are 10000 or 100000 calls the network components between you and the sms gateway can be the culprit. Think off adsl modems/vpn software/routing issues  or even the sms-gateway itself.

If that still doesn't resolve the issue: try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) and or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to deeply inspect http traffic or even tcp/ip traffic.

Comment: And why would you do that and what would the gains be? Please elaborate some more.

Comment: You have to inspect the result being sentback in conjuction with the http- and networktraffic with fiddler and/or wireshark in that case. I'm pretty sure it is not your code that is the problem...